# Tensorflow Android demo: load a custom graph in?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, tensorflow

The [Tensorflow Android demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) provides a decent base for building an Android app that uses a TensorFlow graph, but I've been getting stuck on how to repurpose it for an app that does not do image classification. As it is, it loads in the Inception graph from a .pb file and uses that to run inferences (and the code assumes as such), but what I'd like to do is load my own graph in (from a .pb file), and do a custom implementation of how to handle the input/output of the graph.

The graph in question is from [Assignment 6](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/6_lstm.ipynb) of Udacity's deep learning course, an RNN that uses LSTMs to generate text. (I've already frozen it into a .pb file.) However, the Android demo's code is based on the assumption that they're dealing with an image classifier. So far I've figured out that I'll need to change the values of the parameters passed into `tensorflow.initializeTensorflow` (called in `TensorFlowImageListener`), but several of the parameters represent properties of image inputs (e.g. `IMAGE_SIZE`), which the graph I'm looking to load in doesn't have. Does this mean I'll have to change the native code? More generally, how can I approach this entire issue?

Comment: Any solutions found?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [TensorFlow Serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/) for a generic way to load and serve tensorflow models.

Answer (score 0):

Good news: it recently became a lot easier to embed a pre-trained TensorFlow model in your Android app.  Check out my blog posts here:
https://medium.com/@daj/using-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-on-android-e747831a3d6 (part 1)
https://medium.com/@daj/using-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-on-android-part-2-153ebdd4c465 (part 2)

My blog post goes into a lot more detail, but in summary, all you need to do is:

1. Include the compile `org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+` dependency in your build.gradle.
2. Use the Java `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` class to interface with your model (no need to modify any of the native code).

The TensorFlow Android demo app has been updated to use this new approach.  See [TensorFlowImageClassifier.recognizeImage](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowImageClassifier.java#L127) for where it uses the `TensorFlowInferenceInterface`.

You'll still need to specify some configuration, like the names of the input and output nodes in the graph, and the size of the input, but you should be able to figure that information out [from using TensorBoard](https://medium.com/@daj/how-to-inspect-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-5fd2ee79ced0), or inspecting the training script.